# Simple GridView not xaml binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm just trying to get minimalistic gridview to work using binding in the xaml. If I assign the ItemSource in the code-behind it works fine. What am I missing? Just empty grids when I try to do the xaml binding.

xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="GridView1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyProperties1}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
    <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="GridView2" ItemsSource="{Binding MyProperties2}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<MyGridView1Data> MyProperties1 { get; set; }
    public List<MyGridView2Data> MyProperties2 { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyProperties1 = new List<MyGridView1Data>();
        MyProperties1.Add(new MyGridView1Data());

        MyProperties2 = new List<MyGridView2Data>();
        MyProperties2.Add(new MyGridView2Data());

        //GridView1.ItemsSource = MyProperties1;
        //GridView2.ItemsSource = MyProperties2;
    }
}

public class MyGridView1Data
{
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; } = "12345678901234567892123456789312345678941234567895123456789";
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; } = "12345678901234567892123456789312345678941234567895123456789";
    public string MyProperty3 { get; set; } = "12345678901234567892123456789312345678941234567895123456789";
    public string MyProperty4 { get; set; } = "12345678901234567892123456789312345678941234567895123456789";
    public string MyProperty5 { get; set; } = "12345678901234567892123456789312345678941234567895123456789";
    public string MyProperty6 { get; set; } = "12345678901234567892123456789312345678941234567895123456789";
    public string MyProperty7 { get; set; } = "12345678901234567892123456789312345678941234567895123456789";
    public string MyProperty8 { get; set; } = "12345678901234567892123456789312345678941234567895123456789";
}

public class MyGridView2Data
{
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; } = "12345678901234567892123456789312345678941234567895123456789";
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; } = "12345678901234567892123456789312345678941234567895123456789";
    public string MyProperty3 { get; set; } = "12345678901234567892123456789312345678941234567895123456789";
    public string MyProperty4 { get; set; } = "12345678901234567892123456789312345678941234567895123456789";
    public string MyProperty5 { get; set; } = "12345678901234567892123456789312345678941234567895123456789";
    public string MyProperty6 { get; set; } = "12345678901234567892123456789312345678941234567895123456789";
    public string MyProperty7 { get; set; } = "12345678901234567892123456789312345678941234567895123456789";
    public string MyProperty8 { get; set; } = "12345678901234567892123456789312345678941234567895123456789";
}
```

Comment: After `InitializeComponent();` add: `DataContext = this;`

Comment: Thanks! that worked. Can you please add as answer with a little insight.

Comment: In WPF Every binding needs a `Source` (in this case `MainWindow`) and a `Path` (in this case `MyProperty1`.  When you do not specify the source, the current value of the `DataContext` property is used..    `DataContext` is one of those `DependencyProperties` that gets inherited by contained items.  So if MainWindow's `DataContext` is itself, then the child `StackPanel` and `RadGridView` get the same `DataContext`.   But you must set  its value somewhere first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I assign the ItemSource in the code-behind it works fine. What am I missing? Just empty grids when I try to do the xaml binding.

The actual issue is because you haven't set the [DataContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext?view=net-5.0) of the view, in your specific case `MainWindow`. In order for the `MainWindow` element to participate in data binding, you have to set the `DataContext` property. Since the `DataContext` isn't set, binding isn't happening and why you are not seeing your changes applied.

You can fix your issue a few ways by either:

- Assigning the `DataContext` in code behind
- Adding it to the `Xaml`

Assigning DataContext in code behind

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   DataContext = this; //Assign the datacontext to this instance       
}
```

Adding to Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MyApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
   <local:MainWindow/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help!